# Using a variable as a hash key Perl 5.32

Tags: perl

I am reading user IDs from a csv file and trying to check if that user ID exists in my hash, however I have found that my checking through `if(exists($myUserIDs{"$userID"}))` is never returning true, despite testing with multiple keys that are in my hash.

```
open $file, "<", "test.csv";
while(<$file>)
{
    chomp;
    @fields = split /,/, $_;
    $userID = @fields[1];
    
    if(exists($myUserIDs{"$userID"}))
    {
        #do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use `$fields[1]`?

Comment: `$myUserIDs{"$userID"}` is an over-complicated way to write `$myUserIDs{$userID}`. The quote characters are unnecessary.

Comment: After the `if` try adding: `else { print "Not found [$userID]\n"; }` - putting brackets around the user ID is important because it could make certain issues obvious, like if `$userID` has leading or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I wrote my test csv file with spaces after each comma.
Like 1, 2, 3 instead of 1,2,3 so my keys weren't actually matching. There goes an hour of my time haha.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my (%myUserIDs, @fields);
%myUserIDs = (
                '1' => 'A',
                '4' => 'D'
            );

print Dumper(\%myUserIDs);

while(<DATA>)
{
    chomp;
    @fields = split /,/, $_;
    my $userID = $fields[1];
    
    if(exists($myUserIDs{$userID})){
        print "ID:$userID exists in Hash\n";
    } else {
        print "ID:$userID not exists in Hash\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
A,1
B,2
C,3
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '4' => 'D',
          '1' => 'A'
        };
ID:1 exists in Hash
ID:2 not exists in Hash
ID:3 not exists in Hash
```